# How can I export a multistep webform from an environment to another one?

Tags: 8, webforms, importing-exporting

How can I export a multistep webform from an environment to another one in Drupal 8?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to deploy a webform you've built locally to let's say dev, stage or prod? Or do you mean export the webform and import it in let's say WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Webforms are configuration and you can use the tools D8 provides for this.

Additional to that webform has a unique feature. The form arrays are stored in the yaml format and you can simply copy and paste this from one environment to another.